# The JUnit report missed the karate.call info after * eval if (xxx)

Tags: karate

I use the "* eval if " keyword to handle my complex logic, however, the JUnit HTML report missed the karate.call('delete-user.feature') process.

**The official example:**

```
* eval if (responseStatus == 200) karate.call('delete-user.feature')
```

Then, I can't find the 'delete-user.feature' running info in the JUnit HTML report. And the report stopped in this sentence even though it indeeds get 'delete-user.feature' called (it's logged in the console as expected).

Comment: It works for me. So please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue Reasons why and how are explained in the above link.

Comment: yes, I have reported this issue https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/805